# How to grant previously denied RD rights on a folder?

Tags: windows, permissions

I have denied RD (read data/list directory) on a folder:

```
> icacls mydir /deny "%userdomain%\%username%":(NP)(RD)
```

It is not possible anymore to list the content of that directory:

```
> dir /b mydir
File not found
```

Now, I would like to grant the RD rights back:

```
> icacls mydir /grant "%userdomain%\%username%":(NP)(RD)
processed file: mydir
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

The command seems to work as expected. However, I still can't read the content of the directory:

```
> dir /b mydir
File not found
```

Worse, it seems that I can't do anything anymore on that directory (add files, read existing files when I know the name of the file, delete the directory...).

How can I get my rights back?

Comment: Try to grant full permissions by running CMD as Admin and entering the command `icacls mydir /grant %username%:(OI)(CI)F /T`.

Comment: @harrymc It doesn't work either.

Comment: Next try: `icacls mydir /t /q /c /reset`.

Comment: You might have to manually assign the owner of the file, then add your permissions back to the ACL, you can do this regardless if you have or don't have permissions as an Administrator.

Comment: @harrymc Indeed, it works. However, the `/reset` option is enough.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure to understand. I'm talking about a directory I'm already the owner.

Comment: If you are the owner then the only thing you have to do is explicitly give yourself (or your the user group) explicit permissions to the folder.  You will want to do this through the properties window instead of a command prompt (which by default doesn’t have elevated permissions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved with the command:

```
icacls mydir /t /q /c /reset
```